# SOLR issue - Install Sitecore 10.3

Tags: solr

I'm facing the issue while installing the `Sitecore 10.3` on my local. In the first step followed prerequisites step and install SOLR at the time `SOLR` is not installing it stuck on the 3rd out of 20. Attached the screenshot and log for the reference.

[image]

```
                     ************************************
                           Sitecore Install Framework
                                 Version - 2.3.0
                      ************************************


WorkingDirectory       : C:\Users\Mekala\Downloads\Sitecore 10.3.0
WhatIf                 : False
Verbose                : SilentlyContinue
Configuration          : C:\Users\Mekala\Downloads\Sitecore 10.3.0\Solr-SingleDeveloper.json
Debug                  : SilentlyContinue
AutoRegisterExtensions : False
WarningAction          : Continue
ErrorAction            : Stop
InformationAction      : Continue





[------------------------ TestSolrPath : WriteInformation --------------------]
Solr install path is available.

[--------------------- TestSolrService : WriteInformation --------------------]
Solr service name is available.

[------------------------ TestSolrPort : WriteInformation --------------------]
```

no information apart from this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default Sitecore container configuration uses specific ports. To avoid any conflicts, ensure that the following ports are not being used by another process: `443, 8079, 8081, 8984, and 14330`.

In your case, it seems SOLR is already running, check `http://localhost:8984/solr/#/`. If it is then either you can skip the installation of `SOLR` or stop the service to install a new one.

Check if you have Apache Solr or any other service running on port 8984:

`Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8984).OwningProcess`

If you do, you must stop it:

`Stop-Service -Name "<the name of your service>"`

Comment: I have stopped all the SOLR which is running already. and I have not used above port from the answer i used 8882

Comment: Check if the 8882 port is in use. Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8882).OwningProcess

Comment: port is available